# how to repeat the loop of object properties twice in for / in function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can I repeat the following 'times' object in the for/in loop twice?

```
var times = []
, periods = ['am', 'pm']
, hours = [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
, prop = null
, hour = null;

for (prop in periods) {
for (hour in hours) {
  times.push(('' + hours[hour]) + ':' + '00' + periods[prop]);
}

} // object properties from 12:00am to 11:00pm
```

so I want the output is [12:00am .... 11:00pm (first time loop) ... 12:00am ... 11:00 pm (second time loop]. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Wrap it in another loop, `for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)`?

Answer (score 0):

Build two arrays and [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them:

```
var times1 = []
, times2 = []
, times = []
, periods = ['am', 'pm']
, hours = [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
, prop = null
, hour = null;

for (prop in periods) {
for (hour in hours) {
  times1.push(('' + hours[hour]) + ':' + '00' + periods[prop]);
  times2.push(('' + hours[hour]) + ':' + '00' + periods[prop]);
}

} // object properties from 12:00am to 11:00pm

times = times1.concat(times2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using the *2 function if that doesn't work make a variable that is double of the repeat times.

Add this loop around the other 2 loops and see if that works.

for (2)  {

}

Comment: *"Try using the *2 function"* - What is the "*2" function? Also, `for (2)` is a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome! Try to make sure your answers are clear and if at all possible accompanied by working demonstration code. It's a little difficult to tell from your answer what you're suggesting to the user posting the question. Cheers!